# Why spark-shell fails with NullPointerException?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I try to execute `spark-shell` on Windows 10, but I keep getting this error every time I run it.

I used both latest and spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.4 versions.

```
15/09/22 18:46:24 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in     
CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
15/09/22 18:46:24 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in                 CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
15/09/22 18:46:27 WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in    
metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.2.0
15/09/22 18:46:27 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
15/09/22 18:46:27 WARN : Your hostname, DESKTOP-8JS2RD5 resolves to a loopback/non-reachable address: fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:c0a8:103%net1, but we couldn't find any external IP address!
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.<init>    (ClientWrapper.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala    :163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive(HiveContext.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:168)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSQLContext(SparkILoop.scala:1028)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:9)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:18)
    at <init>(<console>:20)
    at .<init>(<console>:24)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1340)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:974)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.sca      la:108)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$proc      ess$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:991)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$proc      ess$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$proc      ess$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scal      a:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:672)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:650)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.execCommand(FileUtil.java:1097)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:534)
   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:599)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:554)
```

org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:508)
        ... 56 more

```
  <console>:10: error: not found: value sqlContext
               import sqlContext.implicits._
                ^
  <console>:10: error: not found: value sqlContext
               import sqlContext.sql
                ^
```

Comment: I downloaded spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.4 and started spark-shell, but sqlContext loads without a problem for me. I got the same warning messages, **except** for the hostname warning, so my guess is that you'll need to fix your network configutation.

Comment: I can't figure out the cause. I was playing with pre-built package. After I tried downloading the source code `git clone git://github.com/apache/spark.git -b branch-1.6` it worked.

Comment: @Habib Thx. I'm playing with the pre-built package too. Which OS are you using by the way ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I used Spark 1.5.2 with Hadoop 2.6 and had similar problems. Solved by doing the following steps:

1. Download `winutils.exe` from the [repository](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-2.6.0/bin) to some local folder, e.g. `C:\hadoop\bin`.
2. Set `HADOOP_HOME` to `C:\hadoop`.
3. Create `c:\tmp\hive` directory (using Windows Explorer or any other tool).
4. Open command prompt with admin rights.
5. Run `C:\hadoop\bin\winutils.exe chmod 777 /tmp/hive`

With that, I am still getting some warnings, but no ERRORs and can run Spark applications just fine.

Comment: `HADOOP_HOME` is user if system variable? Do you run it on Windows 10? I ask because it isn't working for me...

Comment: Did you set `SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME = localhost`?

Comment: I am still getting some warnings, but no ERRORs.

Comment: Thx, but I have errors still... Where do you have spark dir located? Do you run `spark-shell` command inside bin directory if `bin\spark-shell`?

Comment: It worked fine for me. I guess the key here is to download the right version of the windutils for your platform. I my case I am running a windows 10 in 32 bits and the winutils provided above does not work.Here a link for the 32 version: https://code.google.com/p/rrd-hadoop-win32/source/checkout

Comment: I have Win 8.1 64bit and distribution from [Titus Barik's blog](https://www.barik.net/archive/2015/01/19/172716/) works on my machine.

Comment: Worked for me performing only step 1.

Comment: Worked. Since I didn't install Hadoop, I used my spark directory as the HADOOP_HOME. That is, instead of C:\Hadoop\bin, I used D:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\bin. A dummy "hadoop" directory might have worked too.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing a similar issue, got it resolved by putting the winutil inside bin folder. The Hadoop_home should be set as C:\Winutils and winutil to be placed in C:\Winutils\bin.

Windows 10 64 bit Winutils are available in https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-2.6.0/bin

Also ensure that command line has administrative access.

Refer https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you're running into https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10528. I was seeing the same issue running on Windows 7. Initially I was getting the NullPointerException as you did. When I put winutils into the bin directory and set HADOOP_HOME to point to the Spark directory, I got the error described in the JIRA issue.

Comment: so are you saying that putting HADOOP_HOME to the spark direcotyr, this caused the error?  My HADOOP_HOME is currently set to c:\winutitls, which is not my spark home, and I am currently getting this error

Answer (score 2):

Or perhaps this link here below be easier to follow,

https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems

Basically download and copy winutils.exe to your spark\bin folder. Re-run spark-shell

If you have not set your /tmp/hive to a writable state, please do so.

Comment: Also, It is best that you fire up your spark-shell in /spark/bin folder.

Comment: what does this mean?  As opposed to firing it up where?  Sorry if this question seems crazy, just not sure why people would be firing it up from anywhere else, and I am trying to troubleshoot something myself and I just trying to rule out everything as a cause of failure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give permission to /tmp/hive directory to resolve this exception.

Hope you already have winutils.exe and set **HADOOP_HOME** environment variable. Then open the command prompt and run following command as administrator:

If winutils.exe is present in **D:\winutils\bin** location and **\tmp\hive** is also in D drive:

```
D:\winutils\bin\winutils.exe chmod 777 D:\tmp\hive
```

For more details,you can refer the following links :

[Frequent Issues occurred during Spark Development](http://nishutayaltech.blogspot.nl/2016/04/frequent-issues-occurred-during-spark.html)
[How to run Apache Spark on Windows7 in standalone mode](http://nishutayaltech.blogspot.nl/2015/04/how-to-run-apache-spark-on-windows7-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by placing mysqlconnector jar in spark-1.6.0/libs folder and restart it again.It works.

The important thing is here instead of running spark-shell you should do

```
spark-shell --driver-class-path /home/username/spark-1.6.0-libs-mysqlconnector.jar
```

Hope it should work.

Answer (score 0):

**For Python - Create a SparkSession in your python (This config section is only for Windows)**

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "C:/temp").appName("SparkSQL").getOrCreate()
```

**Copy winutils.exe and keep in C:\winutils\bin and execute the bellow commands**

```
C:\Windows\system32>C:\winutils\bin\winutils.exe chmod 777 C:/temp
```

**Run command prompt in ADMIN mode ( Run as Administrator)**

Answer (score 0):

My issue was having other .exe's/Jars inside the winutils/bin folder. So I cleared all the others and was left with winutils.exe alone. Was using spark 2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved after installing correct Java version in my case its java 8 and setting the environmental variables. Make sure you run the winutils.exe to create a temporary directory as below.

```
c:\winutils\bin\winutils.exe chmod 777 \tmp\hive
```

Above should not return any error. Use `java -version` to verify the version of java you are using before invoking spark-shell.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you need to clone "winutils"

```
git clone https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils.git
```

And

```
set var HADOOP_HOME to DIR_CLONED\hadoop-{version}
```

Remember to choose the version of your hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME` as localhost (on Windows 10) resolved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

type
**SET SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME=localhost**
on your command prompt. Worked for me on windows 11