# Error while invoking spark-shell on windows

Tags: apache-spark, windows-7, installation

I am trying to install apache spark on windows using the steps provided in  [this blog post](https://edumine.wordpress.com/2015/06/11/how-to-install-apache-spark-on-a-windows-7-environment/)

However, I am getting many warnings and errors as shown below:

```
C:\setups\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\bin>spark-shell
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.li
b.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more in
fo.
Using Spark's repl log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults-repl.propertie
s
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel("INFO")

Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.7.0_01)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
Spark context available as sc.
16/04/21 02:04:20 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.api.jdo" is alr
eady registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin i
n the classpath. The URL "file:/C:/setups/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/../lib/d
atanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to regis
ter an identical plugin located at URL "file:/C:/setups/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.
6/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar."
16/04/21 02:04:20 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms" is
 already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plug
in in the classpath. The URL "file:/C:/setups/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/../l
ib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to reg
ister an identical plugin located at URL "file:/C:/setups/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop
2.6/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar."
16/04/21 02:04:20 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is already reg
istered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the cl
asspath. The URL "file:/C:/setups/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/../lib/datanucle
us-core-3.2.10.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an ide
ntical plugin located at URL "file:/C:/setups/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/data
nucleus-core-3.2.10.jar."
16/04/21 02:04:21 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH
 (or one of dependencies)
16/04/21 02:04:23 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH
 (or one of dependencies)
16/04/21 02:04:40 WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore.
hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema versio
n 1.2.0
16/04/21 02:04:41 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning No
SuchObjectException
16/04/21 02:04:42 WARN : Your hostname, RahulBakshee-PC resolves to a loopback/n
on-reachable address: fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:c0a8:173%23, but we couldn't find any ex
ternal IP address!
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.jav
a:522)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.<init>(ClientWrapper.s
cala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(Is
olatedClientLoader.scala:238)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive$lzycompute(HiveCo
ntext.scala:218)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive(HiveContext.scala
:208)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.functionRegistry$lzycompute(Hiv
eContext.scala:462)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.functionRegistry(HiveContext.sc
ala:461)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration.<init>(UDFRegistration.scala:40)

        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<init>(SQLContext.scala:330)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:101)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSQLContext(SparkILoop.scala:10
28)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:15)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:24)
        at <init>(<console>:26)
        at .<init>(<console>:30)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:
1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:
1346)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840
)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:8
57)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.sca
la:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply
(SparkILoopInit.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply
(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoop
Init.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)

        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$Spark
ILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:974)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.s
cala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkIL
oopInit.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:
64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$Spark
ILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:991)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$Spark
ILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$Spark
ILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClass
Loader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$pr
ocess(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSub
mit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:18
1)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1010)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:
715)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:808)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:791)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.execCommand(FileUtil.java:1097)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.
loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:582)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.
getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:557)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(Sess
ionState.java:599)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(Sess
ionState.java:554)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.jav
a:508)
        ... 62 more

<console>:16: error: not found: value sqlContext
         import sqlContext.implicits._

<console>:16: error: not found: value sqlContext
         import sqlContext.sql


scala>
```

Any suggestions on what I can do to resolve this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does starting spark-shell fail with "we couldn't find any external IP address!" on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33792197/why-does-starting-spark-shell-fail-with-we-couldnt-find-any-external-ip-addres)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your host file
RahulBakshee-PC 127.0.0.1

Comment: Some explanation would be useful